# how filtre huge email list by domain with python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i need help with python 
how filtre huge email list by domain with python?
my email list contain different email AOl Gmail Hotmail ....
i want to select one domain ex Gmail and creat a new file contain only gmail adresses

this is the regex function how can i edit it to get only gmail accounts ?

```
regex = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&*+\/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_" "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|" "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))
```

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: Could you explain what kind of answer you expect?

Comment: Please provide some more information, we can really help you with this broad explanation. What kind of data do you have ? is it a CSV-file your reading, are you scaping some data from the web? 
We would love to help you, but you need to put a little more effort into specifying your question.

Comment: this is the regex function how can i edit it to get only gmail accounts  ?
regex = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
                    "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
                    "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of input data?

Anyway, you don't need regex here, just split each email address on its `@` and get the domains.

If you have a string with one address per line, you can do the following.

```
hosts = {}
for address in addresses.splitlines():
    _, host = address.split('@')
    if host not in hosts:
        hosts[host] = [address]
    else:
        hosts[host].append(address)
```